# Master-detail report with custom business objects in Stimulsoft

Tags: c#, stimulsoft

I am working on a project, which uses a custom ORM. Each model is a simple POCO which is populated from the database.

Now, I need to use some of these classes to create a master-detail report in Stimulsoft Reports, and [I am following this guide](http://www.stimulsoft.com/en/articles/stimulsoft-master-detail-tabular-report-using-business-objects). But instead of using ADO.NET entity model, I use our own ORM.

The problem is, at step 5 of the article, Stimulsoft does not recognize my business objects in the **Child of Business Object** box and shows an empty list.

I think, the problem is with the relations between my models. Here is an example of a relation in our ORM:

```
public class Group
{
  public int Id;
  // Other properties
  public List<Person> People { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
  public int Id;
  // Other properties
  public int GroupId;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is too old instruction. Try to add two DataBand with your Business Objects.